# How to pass value from main select query to sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle, subquery

```
    SELECT c.serno,
       NVL (
          (SELECT t1.newvalue
             FROM (  SELECT newvalue
                       FROM applog
                      WHERE     TABNAME = 'cextension'
                            AND rowserno = c.serno -- ERROR
                            AND colname = 'A11103'
                   ORDER BY datetimestamp DESC) t1
            WHERE ROWNUM = 1),
          (SELECT t2.newvalue
             FROM (  SELECT newvalue
                       FROM archapplog
                      WHERE     TABNAME = 'cextension'
                            AND rowserno = c.serno -- ERROR
                            AND colname = 'A11103'
                   ORDER BY datetimestamp DESC) t2
            WHERE ROWNUM = 1)) AS "JoinCreditShieldProgram"
  FROM caccounts c
```

Hi ! i am using oracle DB and trying to run this query but it gives me identifier error on "c.serno" in subquery. Please help me on resolving this error? Thanks.

Comment: Your first problem is using old join syntax for your query. You need to understand the relation and your query is fairly complicated for you.

Comment: You indicate that this is associated with an oracle database, yet you have a sql-server tag. This does not seem correct. Also, can you clarify the error being thrown?

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle? Don't tag products not involved.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a left outer join instead of pure sub queries as shown.

```
SELECT c.serno, NVL(t1.newvalue,t2.newvalue) AS "JoinCreditShieldProgram" FROM
caccounts c LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (SELECT newvalue,rowserno
         FROM (  SELECT newvalue,rowserno
                   FROM applog
                  WHERE     TABNAME = 'cextension'
                        AND colname = 'A11103'
               ORDER BY datetimestamp DESC) 
        WHERE ROWNUM = 1) t1 ON  t1.rowserno = c.serno
        LEFT  OUTER JOIN 
      (SELECT newvalue,rowserno
         FROM (  SELECT newvalue,rowserno
                   FROM archapplog
                  WHERE     TABNAME = 'cextension'
                        AND colname = 'A11103'
               ORDER BY datetimestamp DESC) 
        WHERE ROWNUM = 1) t2   ON t2.rowserno = c.serno;
```

Answer (score 0):

A query that would perhaps be easier to read and understand (although you'd need to test performance) is:

```
SELECT c.serno,
     NVL(t1.newvalue, t2.newvalue) AS "JoinCreditShieldProgram"
FROM   caccounts c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT rowserno,
                               newvalue,
                               row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY rowserno ORDER BY datetimestamp DESC) rn
                        FROM   applog
                        WHERE  tabname = 'cextension'
                        AND    colname = 'A11103') t1 ON c.serno = t1.rowserno AND t1.rn = 1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT rowserno,
                               newvalue,
                               row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY rowserno ORDER BY datetimestamp DESC) rn
                        FROM   archapplog
                        WHERE  tabname = 'cextension'
                        AND    colname = 'A11103') t2 ON c.serno = t2.rowserno AND t2.rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly, If I have to get the last value from two separate tables and then have to do an NVL between the two of them, I prefer using the LAST_VALUE Analytic function.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  c.serno, 
  LAST_VALUE(logs.newvalue) over 
    ( partition by logs.rowserno order by logs.datetimestamp 
      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) AS "JoinCreditShieldProgram"
FROM
  caccounts c
LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT rowserno, newvalue, datetimestamp 
    FROM applog
    WHERE tabname = 'cextension' AND colname = 'A11103'
    UNION
    SELECT rowserno, newvalue, datetimestamp 
    FROM archapplog
    WHERE tabname = 'cextension' AND colname = 'A11103'
  ) logs
ON
  c.serno = logs.rowserno;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
I am not sure why you are using inline view in your query statement.
It is not required you can directly put "rownum" limit and even in more simple way, like below-

SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT c.serno, 
               Nvl (a.newvalue, b.newvalue) AS "JoinCreditShieldProgram" 
        FROM   caccounts c 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN applog a 
                            ON c.serno = a.rowserno 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN archapplog b 
                            ON c.serno = b.rowserno 
        WHERE  a.tabname = 'cextension' 
               AND a.colname = 'A11103' 
               AND b.tabname = 'cextension' 
               AND b.colname = 'A11103' 
        ORDER  BY a.datetimestamp DESC, 
                  b.datetimestamp DESC) 
WHERE  rownum = 1;
```

Comment: That would filter out rows from caccounts that didn't have any values in applog and archapplog. Left outer joins are needed here, not inner joins. Also, the OP is looking for the latest row from applog and archapplog, not all rows.

Comment: I was giving an idea to simplify the query. yes, for exact result some changes were required so, I have updated my query. Hope this will work exactly how it is needed.

Comment: It's still doing an inner join, I'm afraid. You would have avoided the issue if you had used ANSI join syntax. (The lack of (+) on all the a and b columns in the predicate means you're effectively doing an inner join)